# How to write the path of file in FileInputStream() where the file exits in a zip file then a jar file

Tags: java, file, iostream

C:/Data.zip/text.jar/a.xml is the location of `a.xml` so when I am using it like

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStram("C:/Data.zip/text.jar/a.xml");
```

it gives me FileNotFoundException and  also when I am using  `FileInputStream("/a.xml")` throwing same FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Input streams are meant to *read* data from source, not to write them. Could you clarify what you want to achieve here?

Comment: yes correct . I mean how to get the file location for FileInputStrem("fileLocation");

Comment: Note that you can not *simply access* files inside **archives** because an archive is not a folder, it is a single file following some kind of algorithm that describes how to write multiple files into one. It is like if you would have a text file and write all contents of other files into it, then in the end you also have just one file and not a folder. So in order to *access* the contents you need to use the algorithm that **unpacks** the archive again. There are solutions inside the **Java** library that do that for you automatically, as seen in the answer of @albert_nil for example.

Comment: So the bottom line is: To your operating system (and such also for any kind of regular `FIle` methods or `Path` building) an archive like `zip` (or `jar`) just looks like a regular single file. It can not look inside without interpreting the file and using the unpacking algorithm. That is why your current approach can not work (as long as they do not add some magic that does all that stuff automatically).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a JarInputStream in top of the FileInoutStream pointing to the jar, not the xml. Then you need to find that xml file in the JarInoutStream and process it.

```
JarInputStream jarStream = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream("your_jar_path"));
    JarEntry entry;
    while ((jarEntry = jarStream.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
        if (jarEntry.getName().equals("xmlfile_youlookfor")) {
            doyourstuff
        }
     }
}
```

Remember to close stream.

**Edit:** I noticed now that you are talking about a jar inside a zip. But it doesn't change a lot the solution. Just open first the zip with a ZipFileStream and find the jar file inside in a similar way as the above code does with xml inside jar. Then just do the JarInputStream with the found entry inside the zip.

**Edit2:** Some sample code. Haven't tested it, but it should only contain minor typos (if any):

```
public void read() throws IOException {
    ZipInputStream zipStream = null;
    try {
        zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Data.zip"));
        ZipEntry zipEntry;
        boolean zipEntryFound = false;
        while ((zipEntry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            if (zipEntry.getName().equals("text.jar")) {
                zipEntryFound=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!zipEntryFound) {
            return;
        }
        JarInputStream jarStream = new JarInputStream(zipStream);
        JarEntry jarEntry;
        boolean jarEntryFound = false;
        while ((jarEntry = jarStream.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
            if (jarEntry.getName().equals("a.xml")) {
                jarEntryFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!jarEntryFound) {
            return;
        }
        // now your jarStream is positioned on the a.xml file entry, just read 
        // the bytes from the stream. you know how many bytes from the 
        // jarEntry info
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (zipStream != null) {
            zipStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JRE routinely accesses files in JAR, and you can use that capability through ClassLoader. However, accessing a file inside a JAR inside a ZIP is beyond its capabilities. There may be a custom framework somewhere that does that, but I haven't heard of it.

The solution you showed should work in general, assuming you know where the JAR file is. If the JAR is on the classpath, then

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(String name)
```

The "name" is the path to the file, starting from the root of the classpath. The path should start with a "/" or it will be relative.

Comment: ok Steve . can you explain please how to write the path of a file where the file is only inside a jar. Like text.jar->a.xml.